# Dynamically set the size of buffered image

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, jframe, bufferedimage

I'm using this to set the size of my buffered image.

```
Dimension imgDim = new Dimension(700, 380);

BufferedImage gridImage = new BufferedImage(imgDim.width, imgDim.height,
    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

instead of this, I would like to set the size of the image using something like:

```
Dimension imgDim = d;

BufferedImage gridImage = new BufferedImage(d.width/8, d.height/8,
    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

but I'm getting `negativeArraySizeException`

`d` is the dimensions of my `JFrame` which I'm getting using `getMaximumSize()` method

when I print out the value of `d.width/8` its something like 268435455 which I can't make sense of. Is there another way to do this please help

Thank you

Comment: The use of the word 'dynamic' makes me wonder if you expect the image to ***remain*** 1/8th of the size when the frame is **resized.**  Do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> d is the dimensions of my JFrame which I'm getting using `getMaximumSize`() method

You would get d using the `getSize`() method **after** you call the `pack`() method or `setSize`() method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer it works after I call the pack() method can you also please explain what this large number is ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `getSize()` instead of `getMaximumSize()`.

If you don't `setPreferredSize` for your `JFrame`, `getMaximumSize()` will return a very big number. See [Component.getMaximumSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/ComponentUI.html#getMaximumSize%28javax.swing.JComponent%29)

`getSize()` returns your `JFrame's` current size

See [Component JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getSize%28%29)